# Android Facebook C# login not loading internally

Tags: facebook, xamarin.android, facebook-c#-sdk, xamarin

I'm trying to follow [Prabir's blog post about Facebook authentication](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-First-Facebook-Application-v6.aspx) and adapt it in an Xamarin Android-based application.  I have a login page that has the following code defined to generate the URL;

```
private Uri GenerateLoginUrl(string appId, string extendedPermissions)
{
    var parameters = new Dictionary<String, Object> ();

    parameters.Add("client_id", appId);
    parameters.Add ("redirect_uri", "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html");
    parameters.Add("response_type", "token");

    parameters.Add("display", "popup");

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(extendedPermissions))
        parameters.Add("scope", extendedPermissions);

    var fb = new FacebookClient();
    return fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
}
```

On create of the view, I call this method and assign it to a WebView element:

```
var browser = this.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.LoginView);
Uri url = GenerateLoginUrl("<app id>", "");
browser.LoadUrl (url.ToString ());
```

In the view, I have the following defined:

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/LoginView" />
```

When LoadUrl is called, it prompts to open a browser externally (open in Chrome|Firefox|Opera options), not login through the WebView control defined in my view tied to the LoginActivity.  I don't know what is going on here, and why this is happening.  How can I display the request within the webview control, within the application itself and not externally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like the system URL handling is getting in your way. What you need to do is set a [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) on your `WebView`. This will allow you to return `true` from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` (which I believe is the default) which will then allow the requested resource to be loaded by your application.

See the relevant documentation here in [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html), `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` specifically. But the takeaway is

`If WebViewClient is not provided, by default WebView will ask Activity Manager to choose the proper handler for the url.`

Which in the case of an http-based URI, will most certainly be the system browser.

Comment: Interesting.  I will try that out tonight.  Thanks a lot.